# Getting the same value after some time on implementing recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion, websocket

I have implemented a recursive function using `$timeout` to repeatedly perform an update, However, after some time, I am getting the same value as earlier. Can anyone help me understand what's happening?

```
$scope.anotherStrem = function(){   
      $timeout(function(){$scope.anotherStrem()},3000);
    }
```

In the `console.log` output, for the first few minutes, I get different types of values which will be published by a websocket server. But a few minutes later few I have the same value but the websocket sends a different updated value.

Comment: Stop undoing the edit. Your grammar is very difficult to read and this question has exactly nothing to do with angular. The edit is going to help someone figure out how to help you. Making it unreadable again won't help at all.

Comment: actually $timeout belongs to angular. So i mentioned angular